# Finding a record with an exact set of has_many :through association ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to check for an existing InvitationSearch record with the exact same associations BEFORE creating a new one (to avoid having 2 records that are the same) but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
class InvitationSearch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :brands, :through => :invitation_search_brands
  has_many :invitation_search_brands
  has_many :categories, :through => :invitation_search_categories
  has_many :invitation_search_categories
  has_many :sizes, :through => :invitation_search_sizes
  has_many :invitation_search_sizes
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invitation_search
end

class InvitationSearchSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invitation_search
  belongs_to :size  
end

class InvitationSearchBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invitation_search
  belongs_to :brand
end

class InvitationSearchCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invitation_search
  belongs_to :category
end
```

In my invitation_searches_controller create method I want to check for a match before creating a new InvitationSearch.

In my params I get gender, brand_ids, category_ids, and size_ids and I only care about records that have the EXACT gender and same set of associations ids, no more no less.

I know I can do something like the following, but this returns all records that include any of these brands, rather than the exact set. Plus, I need to perform the operation on each association and it seems like that would be rather tedious.

```
InvitationSearch.includes(:brands).where(:brands => {:id => params[:invitation_search][:brand_ids]})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the formatting Michael!

Answer (score 0):

This still looks bad, but is it what you're trying to return?

```
InvitationSearch.includes(:brands)
  .where(:brands => {:id => params[:invitation_search][:brand_ids]})
  .select { |i_s| i_s.brands.count == params[:invitation_search][:brand_ids].count }
```

Second try:

```
q = InvitationSearch.includes(:brands)
params[:invitation_search][:brand_ids].each do |brand_id|
  q = q.where(:brand_id => brand_id)
end
```

Still on the second try, if you're using ruby 1.9.2+, you could use the newer syntax `brad_id: brand_id`.

Comment: Yes, more or less, I am just wondering if the count would be sufficient enough. For example, if my params[:brand_ids] returns [1,3,5] and the first query returns all records that include any of those ids, wouldn't it be possible that the count could return a record with brand_ids such as [1,2,6].

Comment: Edited. How about now? Edit: you know what, maybe I'm too tired for this now. :)